# How to concatenate two dictionary lists together in python?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

Simple dictionary:

`d = {'names': ['a','b','c','d'], 'values': ['1','2','3','4']}`

Desired result:

`x = ['a_1','b_2','c_3','d_4']`

My attempts:

`for k,v in d.values():
    print(str(k)+"_"+str(v))`

raises error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: just do `for k, v in zip(d["names"], d["values"]):`

Comment: Functionally: `for item in map('_'.join, zip(d['names'], d['values'])): print(item)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
d = {'names': ['a','b','c','d'], 'values': ['1','2','3','4']}

for pair in zip(*d.values()):
    print('_'.join(pair))
```

If you want to store it in a list:

```
x = ['_'.join(pair) for pair in zip(*d.values())]
```

If you aren't sure if the order of the `dict` is correct or you aren't using Python 3.7, replace `zip(*d.values())` with `zip(d['names'], d['values'])`.